# Rows and columns restrictions on python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have a list of lists `m` which I need to modify

I need that the sum of each row to be greater than `A` and the sum of each column to be lesser than `B`

I have something like this

```
x = 5     #or other number, not relevant
rows = len(m)
cols = len(m[0])

for r in range(rows): 
    while sum(m[r]) < A:  
        c = randint(0, cols-1)
        m[r][c] += x 

for c in range(cols): 
    cant = sum([m[r][c] for r in range(rows)])
    while cant > B:
        r = randint(0, rows-1)
        if m[r][c] >= x:  #I don't want negatives
            m[r][c] -= x
```

My problem is: I need to satisfy both conditions and, this way, after the second `for` I won't be sure if the first condition is still met.

Any suggestions on how to satisfy both conditions and, of course, with the best execution? I could definitely consider the use of `numpy`

**Edit (an example)**

```
#input
m = [[0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]]
A = 20
B = 25

# one desired output (since it chooses random positions)
m = [[10,0,15],
    [15,0,5]]
```

**I may need to add**

This is for the generation of the random initial population of a genetic algorithm, the restrictions are to make them a possible solution, and I would need to run this like 80 times to get different possible solutions

Comment: Creating such a matrix just by choosing random numbers could take a long time.

Comment: Is the problem solvable? What if A = 100 and B = 1, then no matrices would fit the conditions.

Comment: I have control over A and B values, let's assume it's solvable :B

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample snippet of given input and desired output?

Comment: Looks like is a linear program with `m²` variables and `2m` inequality equations to me. You'll probably want [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). Unroll the matrix into an `m²` vector and optimize for minimum/maximum sum of all values. Have fun formulating the constraints, though.

Comment: that might work not just for this, but for my whole problem, I'll keep checking it out

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should to the trick:

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import linprog

A = 10
B = 20
m = 2
n = m * m

# the coefficients of a linear function to minimize.
# setting this to all ones minimizes the sum of all variable
# values in the matrix, which solves the problem, but see below.
c = numpy.ones(n)

# the constraint matrix.
# This is matrix-multiplied with the current solution candidate
# to form the left hand side of a set of normalized 
# linear inequality constraint equations, i.e.
#
# x_0 * A_ub[0][0] + x_1 * A_ub[0][1] <= b_0
# x_1 * A_ub[1][0] + x_1 * A_ub[1][1] <= b_1
# ...
A_ub = numpy.zeros((2 * m, n))

# row sums. Since the <= inequality is a fixed component,
# we just multiply everthing by (-1), i.e. we demand that
# the negative sums are smaller than the negative limit -A.
#
# Assign row ranges all at once, because numpy can do this.
for r in xrange(0, m):
    A_ub[r][r * m:(r + 1) * m] = -1

# We want that the sum of the x  in each (flattened)
# column is smaller than B
#
# The manual stepping for the column sums in row-major encoding
# is a little bit annoying here.
for r in xrange(0, m):
    for j in xrange(0, m):
        A_ub[r + m][r + m * j] = 1

# the actual upper limits for the normalized inequalities.
b_ub = [-A] * m + [B] * m

# hand the linear program to scipy
solution = linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub)

# bring the solution into the desired matrix form
print numpy.reshape(solution.x, (m, m))
```

**Caveats**

- I use `<=`, not `<` as indicated in your question, because that's what numpy supports.
- This minimizes the total sum of all values in the target vector.
  For your use case, you probably want to minimize the distance
  to the original sample, which the linear program cannot handle, since neither the squared error nor the absolute difference can be expressed using a linear combination (which is what c stands for). For that, you will probably need to go to full [`minimize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

Still, this should get you rough idea.

Comment: the use of .random.random was better, does this also work for non squared matrix?

Comment: I removed that, because  `c` isn't a starting vector, but contains the coefficients of the target function. If you randomize it, you are giving random weights to the variables. As for non-square matrixes: It would need some updates, but the basic function is the same.

Answer (score 0):

A NumPy solution:

```
import numpy as np

val = B / len(m) # column sums <= B
assert val * len(m[0]) >= A # row sums >= A

# create array shaped like m, filled with val
arr = np.empty_like(m)
arr[:] = val
```

I chose to ignore the original content of `m` - it's all zero in your example anyway.

Comment: Nice, but looks like OP wants to shape an initial matrix from a genetic sample to the constraints. A uniform matrix somewhat defeats that purpose ...

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import *

m = [[0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]]
A = 20
B = 25

x = 1     #or other number, not relevant
rows = len(m)
cols = len(m[0])

def runner(list1, a1, b1, x1):
    list1_backup = list(list1)
    rows = len(list1)
    cols = len(list1[0])

    for r in range(rows): 
        while sum(list1[r]) <= a1:  
            c = randint(0, cols-1)
            list1[r][c] += x1

    for c in range(cols): 
        cant = sum([list1[r][c] for r in range(rows)])
        while cant >= b1:
            r = randint(0, rows-1)
            if list1[r][c] >= x1:  #I don't want negatives
                list1[r][c] -= x1
    good_a_int = 0
    for r in range(rows):
        test1 = sum(list1[r]) > a1
        good_a_int += 0 if test1 else 1

    if good_a_int == 0:
        return list1
    else:
        return runner(list1=list1_backup, a1=a1, b1=b1, x1=x1)

m2 = runner(m, A, B, x)
for row in m:
    print ','.join(map(lambda x: "{:>3}".format(x), row))
```